# Colocar Authorization: Basic na api

Tags: php, api, header, authorization

Estou criando uma API como já dito, e preciso usar o **Authorization: Basic KEY** para enviar login e senha via cabeçalho. Infelizmente não tenho noção

`header('Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==');`

Esse código tenho que enviar e em outro código interpretar.. pegar esses dados codificados

Comment: Recomendo postar o codigo que você tentou pelo menos, para que não tranquem a questão... Qual a duvida?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu preciso enviar o `header()` para uma página chamada **api2.php** e nessa página preciso decodificar o código codificado.

Comment: Como você está recuperando o valor?

Comment: @PapaCharlie eu tentei dar um `print_r()` para ver se me informava alguma coisa e não consegui, pois não tenho noção de como fazer.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste exemplo do PNP.NET: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php#73386, veja se é isto que você procura

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu tinha olhado esse exemplo e fiz um teste, só que eu preciso do **authorization: basic KEY** pois iram enviar a requisição via app e eu vou receber esse `header()` no meu php e preciso interpretar. O exemplo do PHP.NET é sobre `WWW-Authenticate` e eu preciso de `authorization: basic KEY`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16294/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-alisson-acioli).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O método de envio e interpretação é bem simples. É *basic* ;)

**Código de Envio**

```
<?php
ob_start();

$user = 'usuário';
$pass = 'senha';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://meusite.com.br/arquivo.php' ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $user . ':' . $pass ) ) );
curl_exec( $ch );
$resposta = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$httpCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $ch );

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");
echo "$httpCode<br>$resposta";
```

**Código do arquivo.php - Recepção dos dados**

```
<?php
$username =
$password = 
$mod = NULL;

// Método para mod_php (Apache)
if ( isset( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) ):
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    $mod = 'PHP_AUTH_USER';

// Método para demais servers
elseif ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] ) ):

    if ( preg_match( '/^basic/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] ) )
      list( $username, $password ) = explode( ':', base64_decode( substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6 ) ) );

    $mod = 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION';

endif;

// Se a autenticação não foi enviada
if ( is_null( $username ) ):

    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Sistema de Testes"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die('Acesso negado.');

// Se houve envio dos dados
else:
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Sistema de Testes"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');

    echo "<p>Olá <strong>{$username}</strong>.</p>";
    echo "<p>Sua senha é <strong>{$password}</strong>.</p>";
    echo "<small>Servidor usando <strong>{$mod}</strong>.</small>";

endif;
```

Note que, na recepção, se o seu servidor usar mod_php não há necessidade de decodificar os dados. O próprio apache se encarrega disso, colocando usuário e senha nas respectivas variáveis de servidor: **$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']** e **$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']**.

Para outros tipos de servidor, há a necessidade de se decodificar e "quebrar" o código enviado.

O código acima não está verificando nem comparando os dados enviados. Apenas verifica se houve envio de autenticação e mostra quais dados foram enviados e qual o método que o recebeu.

Claro que o ideal é verificar usuário e senha, utilizando a seguir o cabeçalho correto:

**Não autenticado**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

**Autenticado - GET**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```

**Autenticado - PUT**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 201 Created');
```

**Autenticado - DELETE**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 204 No Content');
```

**Server Error**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
```

Para uma lista completa, acesse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Uma ferramenta útil para testar os retornos é o site: http://www.hurl.it/

Lembrando sempre que, para fazer uso de comandos como **header**, seu código não pode ter impresso absolutamente nada antes, uma vez que **header** modifica o cabeçalho da página gerada.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: perfeita sua resposta, funcionou mais do que perfeito no que eu precisava!!

Comment: disponha amigo!