# Extrair dados do HTTP Auth com PHP

Tags: php, http

Quero acessar uma URL do meu site da seguinte forma:

```
http://username:password@meusite.com.br
```

Como faço, com PHP, para receber os dados de *Username* e *Password* sem utilizar cURL? Há a possibilidade?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28235/colocar-authorization-basic-na-api/28316#28316

Comment: Somente usando Curl? Não posso colocar em um link `<a>`?

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível utilizando esse formato, e mesmo que fosse você teria sérios problemas de segurança

Comment: Mesmo se eu utilizar `base64_encode`? Minha pergunta tem caráter educativo, Pois gostaria de saber se realmente não é possível.

Comment: acho que não dará certo pelo seguinte: a regra é "http://host:port", o que o navegador fará é considerar "username" um host e "password@meusite.com.br" uma porta (inválida)

Comment: Na verdade a navegação "funciona" e sou "redirecionado" para meusite.com.br, no entanto sem dados de autenticação em lugar nenhum. A resposta definitiva seria: impossivel?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos existem diversos conversores de base64 online, se tu digitar no google aparecem vários... Então não seria uma solução para segurança

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim existe a possibilidade, é só usar as variáveis para [autenticação http](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php), segue um exemplo básico, só para o entendimento do funcionamento

```
$valid_passwords = array("user" => "pass");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);

//se você não colocou o user na url ele mostra a "caixa" autenticação
//caso queira obrigar o usuário a digitar ela url é só tirar o if
if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])){
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
}

$user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : '';
$pass = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : '';



$validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

if (!$validated) {

    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo $user." - ".$pass;
    die("Not authorized");


}
```

Uma observação importante é que no IE eles colocaram uma proteção extra de segurança, talvez não funcione, mais detalhes [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-site-addresses-http-or-https-urls)